# Selenium Python: Click on element with explicit string works but not when string is replaced by variable

Tags: python, html, selenium, variables, findelement

When using the explicit text it works and the found element is clicked on but not when I use the variable:

This is the div:
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-object_name">**68915969-LS**</div>

This works:

```
result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'68915969-LS')]")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(result).click().perform()
```

When I replace '68915969-LS' by a variable nothing happens (no error, found line is not clicked on):

```
doc_number = '68915969-LS'
result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),doc_number)]")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(result).click().perform()
```

Any idea why?

Cheers Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for "doc_number" as a string. You need to resolve your value and join it into your xpath string.

Try this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'"+doc_number+"')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//div[contains(text(),'{doc_number}')]")
```

If you want you can also f string and put your variable in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
You're absolutly right. Somehow I struggled that the xpath is just a string...
I used this one and it worked fine :

```
result=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'%s')]"% str(doc_number))
```